# Amazon SNS configuration for Data Pipeline success and failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-data-pipeline

I am using the Amazon `data pipeline` for the automation of some `shell` activity. Which will run once in a day. So, I was configuring the amazon `SNS` for letting me know whether the last run of the `shell` activity was successful or fail. If, failed then email me the reason of failure.

So, I was able to configure the `SNS` for sending me the mail. But, how should I configure the message part of `SNS` so that in case of failure, it send me the exact error?  Also, in case of success send me the status `SUCCESS`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try node references to refer to the object on which the action is added http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-pipeline-expressions.html shows how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is my working Dynamo -> S3 import.
https://gist.github.com/osvadimos/2954ce4c0f7fc249594c999822e639f2

Regarding your question.
First you have to create Fail/Success Object

```
public static PipelineObject getSNSFailActivity() {
    String name = "FailureNotify";
    String id = "FailureNotify";

    Field type = new Field()
            .withKey("type")
            .withStringValue("SnsAlarm");

    Field topicArn = new Field()
            .withKey("topicArn")
            .withStringValue("#{myTopicFail}");

    Field role = new Field()
            .withKey("role")
            .withStringValue("DataPipelineDefaultRole");

    Field subject = new Field()
            .withKey("subject")
            .withStringValue("FAIL: #{node.@scheduledStartTime}");

    Field message = new Field()
            .withKey("message")
            .withStringValue("#{myDDBTableName}");


    List<Field> fieldsList = Lists.newArrayList(type,
            role,
            topicArn,
            subject,
            message);

    return new PipelineObject()
            .withName(name)
            .withId(id)
            .withFields(fieldsList);
}
```

You have to add reference of Fail/Success object to your S3BackupLocation object

```
public static PipelineObject getS3BackupLocation() {
    String name = "S3BackupLocation";
    String id = "S3BackupLocation";

    Field type = new Field()
            .withKey("type")
            .withStringValue("S3DataNode");
    Field directoryPath = new Field()
            .withKey("directoryPath")
            .withStringValue("#{myOutputS3Location}#{format(@scheduledStartTime, 'YYYY-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss')}");
    Field onFail = new Field()
            .withKey("onFail")
            .withRefValue("FailureNotify");
    Field onSuccess = new Field()
            .withKey("onSuccess")
            .withRefValue("SuccessNotify");

    List<Field> fieldsList = Lists.newArrayList(type,
            directoryPath,
            onFail,
            onSuccess);

    return new PipelineObject()
            .withName(name)
            .withId(id)
            .withFields(fieldsList);
}
```